# Laravel Homestead Installation on Windows

Tags: laravel, windows, vagrant, homestead, vagrant-windows

I tried to set up a homestead for my projects, but I get an error during the "vagrant up" command.

My error:

**Bringing machine 'homestead' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/vagrant-2.2.7/plugins/provisioners/file/config.rb:20:in `expand_path': incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and Windows-1254 (Encoding::CompatibilityError)**

I think I get this error because of the character in the user folder.
My user folder: "C: \ Users \ Hilal Gür".

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your folder path

Here's a similar issue to your problem
https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/3937

The issue looks pretty dead to me, I believe they won't fix it in anytime soon,

I think it's because your  directory name has special character in it the "ü" character

Here are my suggestions to your problem:

- Try changing directory, make sure the full path doesn't have special character in it, maybe try other drive, like D: or E:
- Try to change your user account

Comment: is this answer your question @Hilal GÜR

Comment: Thank you so much @ThatBuffDude.

I created a new user and tried again. This time it happened.

My username included the letter "ü". This was not true. So I was getting an error because of this character. So I created a new user and re-installed.

Comment: Hmm sorry I don't quiet get that, did you mean you created a new user, without a special character and the issue still persist? 

Do you mind to give me the full path of your homestead working directory? Make sure your homestead dir doesn't have unicode in it.

I tried to google your problem and seems like every issue and I found similar problem, and all referring to the use of unicode somewhere along the path in their working directory

Comment: Well basically homestead is an OS  with pre-installed  php tools, and you don't have to use homestead for it. Alternatively you can use project like 

https://github.com/cytopia/devilbox or
https://github.com/laradock/laradock

to setup your working environment, but required a little of knowledge on how to use docker IMO

Comment: The problem was fixed when I created and created a new user account. The problem was caused by the Turkish character in my user name.